# Testing Minio with K6, but despite large number of VUs sending, the number of requests is very small

Tags: node.js, nestjs, k6

I'm currently using K6 to load test a simple API that downloads objects from a Minio server.  I am using NestJS to test the API. The main function being called is `downloadObject`, which downloads objects from Minio using the stream API provide by nodejs. Here is my NestJS service and k6 configuration file:

```js
@Injectable()
export class S3Service {
  private readonly minioClientCache: Map<string, minio.Client> = new Map();

  async getS3Client() {
    const endpoint = this.configService.get('s3.endpoint');

    if (!this.s3ClientCache.has(endpoint)) {
      const s3 = new S3({
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        forcePathStyle: true,
        tls: false,
        region: 'us-west-1',
        endpoint: this.configService.get('s3.endpoint'),
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: this.configService.get('s3.accessKey'),
          secretAccessKey: this.configService.get('s3.secretKey'),
        },
      });
      this.s3ClientCache.set(endpoint, s3);
    }
    return this.s3ClientCache.get(endpoint);
  }

  generateRandomString(length: number) {
    let result = '';
    const characters =
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length),
      );
    }
    return result;
  }

  async downloadObject(s3Path: string) {
    const s3Client = await this.getS3Client();

    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: 'artifacts',
      Key: s3Path,
    });

    try {
      const response = await s3Client.send(command);
      const inputStream = response.Body;
      const subFolderName = this.generateRandomString(10);
      if (!fs.existsSync(`./s3_objects/${subFolderName}`)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(`./s3_objects/${subFolderName}`);
      }

      const downloadPath = `./s3_objects/${subFolderName}/${basename(s3Path)}`;

      const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath);

      if (inputStream instanceof Readable) {
        console.log('inputStream has been piped');
        inputStream.pipe(outputStream);
      }
      outputStream.on('finish', function () {
        console.log('File downloaded successfully');
        return HttpStatus.CREATED;
      });
      outputStream.on('error', function () {
        console.log('Error downloading file');
        return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
import http from 'k6/http';
import { sleep, check } from 'k6';

export const options = {
  discardResponseBodies: true,
  scenarios: {
    load: {
      executor: 'ramping-vus',
      startVUs: 0,
      stages: [
        { duration: '5m', target: 50 },
        { duration: '5m', target: 200 },
        { duration: '5m', target: 0 },
      ],
      tags: { test_type: 'load' },
      gracefulRampDown: '5m',
    },
  },
  thresholds: {
    'http_req_duration{test_type:load}': ['p(99)<180000'],
  },
};

export default async function () {
  const url = 'http://localhost:4000/api/s3/object/download';
  const data = {
    s3Path: 'TEST_PATH/2463/test.zip',
  };
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  };
  await http.asyncRequest('POST', url, data, {
    headers,
    timeout: '240s',
  });
  sleep(1);
}
```

I'm not sure why, but K6 is only able to send 1-4 requests at a time, despite the large number of VUs executing the javascript file. I was thinking this may be because of how I implemented file streaming, but I'm not sure.  Any thoughts? Here is what the data looks like:

[image: k6 load test results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of VUs doesn't tell you anything about the request rate. A single VU will perform a single request, wait until that request is finished, then start the next request. Since your requests seem to take more than 16 seconds, judging from the screenshot; that means a single VU will send less than 4 requests per minute. With 60 VUs that will correspond to 4 requests per second.

If you want to control the request rate, don't use a VU executor, but use an arrival-rate executor instead, e.g. the [`ramping-arrival-rate` executor](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/executors/ramping-arrival-rate/). Arrival-rate executors will inject additional VUs to achieve the desired request rate.

Of course, that won't help much if your service is already overloaded with a small number of VUs/requests. Looking at the screenshot again, your service's minimum latency is already 10+ seconds with less than 20 concurrent users.

As to why your service is so slow, that should probably be a separate post (only one question per post: either "why does k6 only send a low number of requests" or "why is my minio service only handling a low number of concurrent requests").